# Web Api Concurrency Issues Checking if Item Exists

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, concurrency

I have a page making 2 ajax calls to a `Web Api` method that does the following logic:

1. Checks if the item exists. If so, retrieve the item.
2. If item does not exist, create it.

Code:

```
if (!_db.Items.Any(x => x.EntityId == requestItem.EntityId &&                            
                            x.UserId == request.UserId))
{
    // item does not exist, so create it.
    var item = new Item(); 
    // set some properties here...

    _db.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The problem  I'm having is that items are being created very fast and since the ajax calls are running concurrently, I end up with two items.  But I only want to allow 1 to be created.  I don't want to throw an error back to the user. I want to be able to only create an item if one **truly** does not exist. How can I achieve this?

I saw this [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/817432/Optimistic-Concurrency-in-Entity-Framework-Code-Fi) on setting of concurrency checks with Entity Framework but I don't want to throw an error back to the user so I'm not sure if setting up EF concurrency is what I need to do. Values aren't overwriting each other.  Two calls are happening at the (near) same time so both see that there are 0 items in the table.

Comment: If you don't want error back to user, simply wrap the process with a try-catch.

Comment: I'm not running into data overwriting a previous value. So checking a RowVersion property won't work because the item doesn't exist yet.  I'm having trouble restricting 1 item to be created.

Comment: Is making a composite unique key acceptable?

Comment: How about just using a database transaction? Though you would have to use Serializable..

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a unique identifier in your request to be able to determine double posting on the server.

What I'd suggest is that on page load generate a UID.
When the user clicks the button that sends the request to the web api, pass the generated UID.

Now, if the user clicks the button numerous times it will still pass the same value for the UID because it is generated on page load not on user click.

On the server, do the same checking.

```
if (!_db.Items.Any(x => x.EntityId == requestItem.EntityId &&                            
                            x.UserId == request.UserId))
{
    // item does not exist, so create it.
    var item = new Item(); 
    // set some properties here...

    _db.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I'd suggest using the UID from the request as the `requestItem.EntityId`

No need to add a try-catch block since you are using a simple if-statement which is sufficient. You better find a javascript UUID generating code or library :)

Comment: Thanks but I'm don't need to prevent a double post.  I want to be able to handle it if clients are doing parallel ajax promises.